# I'm unable to change the default style by bootstrap on a navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the looks of a default navbar by bootstrap to a costume looking navigation bar by using a separate css file but the changes won't apply. I have linked the css file after the bootstrap files but I still can't alter the looks of the navbar. Any idea why is this happening? Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Fashion</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand pull-left">Trunk Club</a>
    </div><!-- End of navbar-header -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a class="getstarted" href="#howitworks">How it Works</a></li>
        <li><a class="getstarted" href="#whattoexpect">What to Expect</a></li>
        <li><a class="getstarted" href="#stylists">Stylists</a></li>
        <li><a class="getstarted" href="#login">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a class="getstarted" href="#getstarted">Get Started</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   </nav>
```

And here's the CSS file:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #151e28;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

ul {

    margin-top: 20px
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: #878b85;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
    border-left: 1px solid #878b85;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;   
}

nav ul li:nth-child(5) {
    border: 1px solid #878b85;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: add `!important` to the end of each line of css code you want to overwrite should work.

Comment: Your code is good. Try clearing the browser cache.  This is your code and its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/mao0kymx/

Answer (score 0):

The best way of overriding BS's native styling is to be more specific on the elements you want to change: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

For example, if you want to override BS's `.navbar-brand` class, choose a selector further up the tree (a parent) and use that as the parent / child selector when writing your CSS:

```
.parentclass .navbar-brand {
    // CSS properties
}
```

Also ensure your custom CSS file is referenced **AFTER** BS's.

**NB:** Using the above technique will ensure you **DO NOT have to use `!important`** to override BootStrap. I strongly advise you to use `!impotant` ONLY when all else fails, it should not be the first port of call.

EXAMPLE: https://jsfiddle.net/2o4ct6pv/

As you can see from the JSFiddle I've provided, I've simply used the following:

```
.parent .navbar-default {
  background-color: red;
}
```

And the element with a class of `.navbar-default` now has a `background-color` of `red` as opposed to BootStrap's native `#f8f8f8`.

Comment: I was able to alter the .navbar-brand by adding its parent but .navbar's parent element is only body from what what I can understand and it doesn't alters anything.

Comment: @GeorgeKech Even adding `body .navbar` will make its specificity increase over BS's native. Try also using `nav.navbar`

Comment: Didn't work. The only thing that alters the looks is when I use .nav but it's not correct. It looks like it styles only the parts contained in the container.

Comment: @GeorgeKech `.navbar-inverse` might be overriding it then. Try `nav.navbar.navbar-inverse`

Comment: @GeorgeKech or try removing `.navbar-inverse` altogether?

Comment: I tried the "nav.navbar.navbar-inverse" which didn't change anything. Removing the .navbar-inverse works style wise but I want for the navbar to collapse in smaller screens as for the button on the right to appear.

Answer (score 0):

To override CSS from another stylesheet you can:

1. Add your CSS file after the one you want to overwrite (which you
   have done) in the **HEAD** tag
2. Make sure the CSS definition/rule is
   exactly the same as the one you want to overwrite e.g. If it's

   > .nav > .nav-default

you must have the same rule

3. use **!important** e.g.

   > color: #000000 !important

Number 3 is the most important one